# jsp not found using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jetty, filenotfoundexception

Trying to integrate hibernate into struts2 framework.
Cant see what im doing wrong atm. Jetty cant find jsp's

`SEVERE: PWC6117: File "/Users/juliusskye/flightpub/src/main/webapp/pages/login.jsp" not found`

[image]

struts file

```
<struts>

<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="Pages" namespace="/pages" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login"
    method ="authenticate"
            class="FPG2.view.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/pages/welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="results"
    method ="execute"
            class="FPG2.view.ResultsAction">
            <result name="success">/pages/error.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/pages/results.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

login Action Class

```
package FPG2.view;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
    public static final String USERNAME = "label.username";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "label.password";
    private String username = "Username";
    private String password = "Password";

    public String authenticate() {

     if (this.username.equals("admin") 
                && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            addActionError(getText("error.login"));
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>FlightPub - Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password"  key="label.password" size="20" />

    <s:submit method="authenticate" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>FlightPub</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This could be a problem with classloader, did you test it with Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong path defined in struts.xml, you forget about WEB-INF folder